# Apt-cache search only specified source

Tags: debian, apt

I use backtrack and I have a Packages.gz file with some packages on my hard drive. I want to use "apt-cache search" to search only the folder which contain Packages.gz. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [grep-dctrl](http://man.cx/grep-dctrl%281%29) which is part of the [dctrl-tools](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=dctrl-tools) package.

For example:

```
$ grep-dctrl -ns Package -F Filename mplayer2_2.0~git20120817-dmo1_amd64.deb www.deb-multimedia.org_dists_wheezy_main_binary-amd64_Packages 
mplayer2
```

`-n` means to only print the value of the fields, not the label. `-s Package` means to only print the Package field. `-F Filename` means to only search the filename field. `mplayer2…deb` is what to search for. `www…_Packages` is the file to search.

I'm not sure if it'll search a .gz file directly, but it will search stdin, so you can just use a pipe: `zcat Packages.gz | grep-dctrl …`

**edit:** Given you have the actual `.deb`, not just the file name, you can also use [`dpkg-deb`](http://man.he.net/man1/dpkg-deb) to get the info. Here is an example with wireshark:

```
$ dpkg-deb --showformat='${package}\n' -W a.deb
wireshark
```

and, to explain `--showformat` lets you format the output (here, getting just the package name, instead of package and version, which is the default); `-W` says to print formatted info about a binary package. `a.deb` is of course the .deb package to print info about (I renamed it to show that it isn't just spitting back out the filename).

Answer (score 1):

Why use apt-cache? zgrep will do for searching in a single file...

Comment: the thing is I want to find out a package name (e.g. "adobereader-enu" for "AdbeRdr9.5.4-1_i386linux_enu.deb" file). or maybe there is another way than using "apt-cache"?

Comment: `zgrep -i 'ad.?be; /path/to/packages.gz`